# How to configure database.yml for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vps, dokku

I would like to deploy my application via `Dokku` to a VPS. 
Putting together the `dokku-postgres` [documentation](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres) and the relative, scarce internet documentation on the matter ([one](https://gist.github.com/joshteng/895ba92a281c0d477089) at GitHub), it seems necessary to configure `database.yml` to use the url environment variable `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>`

Since I could not find any other sources of information, I wonder how `database.yml` should be configured, and **how Rails will connect to the postgres service created with Dokku**.

For instance, taken for granted that linking `url` to the `DATABASE_URL` variable is necessary, will this be enough to establish a connection between my Rails application and the postgres service or would it be still necessary to use a username and a password? In the latter case, what username and password am I expected to use?

Below is how at present my `database.yml` looks like.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: asarluhi

development:
  <<: *default
  database: fireworks_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: fireworks_app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: fireworks_app_production
  pool: 25
  username: fireworks_app
  password: <%= ENV['FIREWORKS_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

This file was created as it is (apart from a higher pool size for production) when I created the application. How would you suggest to edit the `production` section?

The dokku-postgres documentation states that the following (and nothing else) will be set on the linked application by default:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:SOME_PASSWORD@dokku-postgres-lolipop:5432/lolipop
```

In place of the lollipop postgres service example, I would use `fireworks_app_production` to match the name of the database in `database.yml` 
Are *username* and *password* still necessary after pointing `url` to the `DATABASE_URL` variable? Am I expected to add or remove anything else?

Comment: The settings that you enter in `database.yml` are merged with the options from ENV["DATABASE_URL"]. The settings from ENV take precedence. So yes your `pool` option will be used. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: Would my `pool` option be merged if I decided to add `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` in `database.yml`? As the documentation you linked states, this would be a best practice.

Comment: Adding `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` explicitly in your `database.yml` is not necessary or a best practice since the database connector uses `ENV['DATABASE_URL']`  anyways by default.  Its just an example to show the concept / best practice that you should use an ENV var in production instead of checking in your database credentials.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry about the database.yml with dokku, just upload your app to the server, let's use "fireworks" as the name for example on this.

when you upload the first time the app, this is created automatically so you don't need to create it.

then you install the postgres plugin and run

```
# that will create the container for the database
$ dokku postgres:create fireworks
# and then you link both, the app with the database
$ dokku postgres:link fireworks fireworks
```

you don't have to worry about anything else, with that dokku will connect this

then you just have to run `db:migrate` and everything is ready to work!

Comment: I am not sure I should run `db:create`, considering that the application is already linked with the (already created) fireworks postgres service. Documentation says I should run only `db:migrate`. See for instance: http://donpottinger.net/blog/2014/11/17/bye-bye-heroku-hello-dokku.html

Comment: See also at the very bottom of the following page: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-digitalocean-image-to-run-a-ruby-on-rails-app

Comment: You are right, just run the db:migrate and don't worry about the create

Comment: You never really use `db:create` in production since the database user in production should not have the privileges to create or drop databases (this limits the potential damage if the server is compromised).